# Unexpected behaviour of user.authenticate() with Rails in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, activemodel, bcrypt-ruby

I want to make an acceptance test for the signing in flow, and I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour of `user.authenticate` method.

Authentication in development environment works as expected: a POST with email and plain password pair passes it perfectly. The problem arises when I run tests: authentication with plain password fails. But strangely it succeeds with **password's hash**.

Here's the code:

`class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase)
    logger.debug Rails.env
    logger.debug "password #{params[:password]}"
    logger.debug user.authenticate(params[:password]).to_yaml
    ...`

And here are logs for different environments:

`env development
  password 123456
  --- !ruby/object:User`

`env test
  password 123456
  --- false`

`env test
  password $2a$10$70AlnpaXIMHtjDUei/1HU.OSEG4WVjW6ens3jzN04bC8SOxTv2Ftm
  --- !ruby/object:User`

Any idea what can I do so that authentication succeeds with plain passwords in the test environment?

I'm using `bcrypt-ruby` for passwords in ActiveModel objects.

Thanks.

Comment: How is user created in test?

Comment: It's either a fixture from users.yml or FactoryGirl generated object. In the test database, password hash is always a bcrypt product.

Comment: john:
  first_name: John
  password_digest: $2a$10$R1kxWTCTO/u3YsbEwI6WRO4b2BfPCfLlktyTt2HtblL1YF4pZEskG # 123456

Comment: factory :user do
    first_name "Gustav"
    password { BCrypt::Password.create("123456") }

Comment: @BroiSatse Just saw it. Could it be that referencing password_digest from fixtures and password from FactoryGirl generator is the root of all evil? Will check right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
factory :user do 
   first_name "Gustav"
   password { BCrypt::Password.create("123456") }
end
```

You're creating a password being digest for given string. Change it to:

```
 password "123456"
 password_confirmation { password }
```

and let BCrypt create the digest.